# Elastic & Relational DB

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch, lucene

I’m having difficulty understanding how to architect the back-end of a search application which will require searching over 1m+ documents and would like some advice on the following as it relates to using a lucene based index and a relational store:

1. Should the UI only search against Elastic and the primary relational store act as a good copy store?
2. If my data is inherently relational (let’s say I have two tables, recipes mid ingredients) that rely on joins, how will I present search results to the user when they’re data is being searched against and presented from only elastic?
3. When users make edits to the data, the updated edits get stored in the relational store. Would I then kick off a re-index of elastic of the delta so it becomes immediately searchable in the application? More of an opinion.

I believe my lack of understanding stems from not knowing the interplay between elastic and a traditional DB. Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just a beginner with Elasticsearch, but I have implemented a similar project. Different people may have different opinions about these questions, so I am just going to explain what I have done to solve a similar problem:

**Question 1:** In my project, I am using Elasticsearch for search. My Relational DB (MySQL) is the primary source of data. In order to achieve this, I am synchronizing ES with MySQL. This synchronization process is a common practice and there are different approaches that you can take. Personally I chose the approach [explained here](https://qafoo.com/blog/086_how_to_synchronize_a_database_with_elastic_search.html). There is also an open source project [go-mysql-elasticsearch](https://github.com/siddontang/go-mysql-elasticsearch) for this purpose.

**Question 2:** This is a broad question, but it is common to [denormalize](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/denormalization.html) ES data. [See this article about data modeling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/modeling-your-data.html)

**Question 3:** I my case I took the approach of synchronizing ES with MySQL as explained above.